# vagrant box download cache and unzip

Tags: vagrant

So I am trying to download a box that is in a .zip format like so:

```
vagrant box add win7-ie10 http://aka.ms/ie10.win7.vagrant
```

After downloading, I get this error

```
bsdtar: Invalid central directory signature
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors."
```

My questions are

1. Does anyone know if that's because it's a zip? If so, is there a way I could automated the process of downloading it.
2. Does vagrant cache this download somewhere I could reuse? It's a 4.5GB file so I don't wanna download it again. I have looked into the `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/win7-ie10/0` directory, but it is empty.

Answer (score 3):

1. `vagrant box add` will only add `.box` file. box files are already compressed so you should not need to zip on top of it. and if its anyway zip, make sure to unzip before you run the command
2. check your `~/.vagrant.d/tmp` folder, you should have the large file you have downloaded

Comment: the `~/.vagrant.d/tmp` filder is empty unfortunately :(

Comment: hum, in this case you would need to download again. you can download the file (wget or curl) and after do `vagrant add box` from the downloaded file

Comment: The downloaded file is a zip archive containing a single `.box` file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with bsdtar and this image during extraction of `vagrant box add`.

The solution was to download the *.zip file* with firefox to my desktop and extract it. The extraction was no problem so the file seems to be okay.

Then use the *.box file* instead of an URL. This command added the box successfully:

```
     vagrant box add IE11\ -\ Win7.box  --name win7-basebox
```